# Recursive object-listing

Tags: r, list

Is there an elegant way in R to recursively turn an arbitrary deep list (containing lists and vectors) into a vector of paths? For example, convert this:

```
list(
  home = list(
    jerry = c("R", "bla"),
    mary = "xx"
  ),
  tmp = c("foo", "bar"),
  c("etc")
)
```

To an object as this:

```
c(
  "/home/jerry/R",
  "/home/jerry/bla",
  "/home/mary/xx",
  "/tmp/foo",
  "/tmp/bar",
  "/etc"
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names in `unlist` do approximately what you want:

```
> test <- list(
+     home = list(
+         jerry = c("R", "bla"),
+         mary = "xx"
+     ),
+     tmp = c("foo", "bar"),
+     etc = c()
+ )
> unlist(test)
home.jerry1 home.jerry2   home.mary        tmp1        tmp2 
        "R"       "bla"        "xx"       "foo"       "bar"
```

Handles multiple levels of recursion as well:

```
> test <- list(
+     home = list(
+         jerry = list(a="R", b="bla"),
+         mary = list(c="xx")
+     ),
+     tmp = list(d="foo", e="bar"),
+     etc = list(nothing=NULL)
+ )
> unlist(test)
home.jerry.a home.jerry.b  home.mary.c        tmp.d        tmp.e 
         "R"        "bla"         "xx"        "foo"        "bar"
```

From there it's easy to add the last little bit you want (having the final value be the last path elemtn) on:

```
> unl <- unlist(test)
> res <- names(unl)
> res <- paste(res,unl,sep=".")
> res
[1] "home.jerry.a.R"   "home.jerry.b.bla" "home.mary.c.xx"   "tmp.d.foo"        "tmp.e.bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

As long as none of your list elements have names that include dots (and with the exception of that troublesome `NULL`-valued `etc` element in your list), this should work:

```
ll <- rapply(l, function(X) sapply(X,list), how="replace") #for tip element names
nms <- names(unlist(ll))
gsub(".", "/", nms, fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "home/jerry/R"   "home/jerry/bla" "home/mary/xx"   "tmp/foo"       
# [5] "tmp/bar"
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the `etc` to be a vector instead of a name. Now it works great.

Answer (score 3):

For a more general approach, including posdibly names with dots and null elements, use this:

```
f <- function(test, parent=character(0))
{
    if( is.null(test) ) return(parent)

    if( is.list(test) )
    {
        result <- character(0)

        for( i in seq_along(test) )
        {
            result <- c(result, Recall(test[[i]], parent=paste0(parent,"/",names(test)[i])))
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result <- paste0(parent,"/",as.character(test))
    }

    result
}

f(test)

#[1] "/home/jerry/R"   "/home/jerry/bla" "/home/mary/xx"   "/tmp/foo"        "/tmp/bar"        "/etc"
```

Comment: Cool. Great use of `Recall` for recursive calling of an anonymous function.

Comment: Super. Thanks for this. I'm sure I'll use it as a template for other tree-walking functions in the future.

Comment: :-) @JoshO'Brien, the key idea is to have an argument to keep track of your depth level (defaulting to zero or null or something alike).

Comment: @Jeroen, technically, the function is not anonymous since it is bound to a symbol (`f`). I've chosen `Recall` to avoid bugs in case one assigns it to other symbol.