# Flatten nested list into 1-deep list

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient solution to (recursively) flatten a nested list (of arbitrary depth) into non-nested, 1 deep list. The list elements are not homogeneous, therefore they should not be unlisted into a vector (that would coerce all values to a single type). The best solution so far is:

```
flatlist <- function(mylist){
    lapply(rapply(mylist, enquote, how="unlist"), eval)
}
```

This does almost what I want:

```
> flatlist(list(foo=TRUE, bar=456, pets=list(cat="meeuw", dog="woof")))
$foo
[1] TRUE

$bar
[1] 456

$pets.cat
[1] "meeuw"

$pets.dog
[1] "woof"
```

However, a problem is that `rapply` is dropping `NULL` values, which is undesired:

```
> flatlist(list(foo=123, bar=NULL))
$foo
[1] 123
```

I would like that `NULL` elements appear in the output, either as `NULL` or as `NA`. Also the double loop with `enquote` and then `eval` makes things a bit slow. This function is used extensively in my code. Is there a way to do it all in one run?

Comment: You could almost certainly adapt the code in [@Ferdinand.kraft's excellent answer to a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679067/recursive-object-listing/16679358#16679358). In fact, looking at the comments there, it looks like you've already seen that answer!

Comment: That solution is really inefficient, probably because of `result <- c(result, .....`. I was hoping for something more native.

Comment: I would recommend checking [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139677/how-to-flatten-a-list-to-a-list-without-coercion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the `rapply` part by your own recursion so `NULL`s are not getting any special treatment:

```
renquote <- function(l) if (is.list(l)) lapply(l, renquote) else enquote(l)

lapply(unlist(renquote(ml)), eval)
```

Comment: I guess this is the only correct solution. It is not as fast as the native `rapply` but it will do. Thanks!

Comment: Note that is.list() also returns TRUE for data.frames. Alternatively use: if( class(l) == 'list') {...}.